# Bike constructor keeps adding the gears instead of outputting specified amount

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm currently learning Javascript and am learning basic `OOP` at [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/make-object-properties-private#?solution=var%20Car%20%3D%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20a%20private%20variable%0A%20%20var%20speed%20%3D%2010%3B%0A%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20these%20are%20public%20methods%0A%20%20this.accelerate%20%3D%20function%28change%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20speed%20%2B%3D%20change%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20this.decelerate%20%3D%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20speed%20-%3D%205%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20this.getSpeed%20%3D%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20speed%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avar%20Bike%20%3D%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Only%20change%20code%20below%20this%20line.%0A%20%20var%20gear%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20this.setGear%20%3D%20function%28switchGear%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20gear%20%2B%3D%20switchGear%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20this.getGear%20%3D%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20gear%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avar%20myCar%20%3D%20new%20Car%28%29%3B%0A%0Avar%20myBike%20%3D%20new%20Bike%28%29%3B%0A). I'm at this point where I'm creating an object and am trying to get this object to return what I would like it to return.

The entire description of this project is:

> Objects have their own attributes, called properties, and their own functions, called methods.
>
> In the previous challenges, we used the this keyword to reference public properties of the current object.
>
> We can also create private properties and private methods, which aren't accessible from outside the object.
>
> To do this, we create the variable inside the constructor using the var keyword we're familiar with, instead of creating it as a property of this.
>
> This is useful for when we need to store information about an object but we want to control how it is used by outside code.
>
> For example, what if we want to store the speed our car is traveling at but we only want outside code to be able to modify it by accelerating or decelerating, so the speed changes in a controlled way?
>
> In the editor you can see an example of a Car constructor that implements this pattern.
>
> Now try it yourself! Modify the Bike constructor to have a private property called gear and two public methods called getGear and setGear to get and set that value.

Now I understand the basic concept of how this works and I'm understanding what I'm doing, however I'm also using the `node terminal` to try and debug this myself, I've come to the conclusion that the program is adding the gears together every time:

```
> var Bike = function() {
...
...   // Only change code below this line.
...   var gear = 0;
...
...   this.setGear = function(switchGear){
...     gear += switchGear;
...   };
...
...   this.getGear = function() {
...     return gear;
...   };
... };
undefined
> var myBike = new Bike();
undefined
> myBike.setGear(4);
undefined
> myBike.getGear();
4
> myBike.setGear(4);
undefined
> myBike.getGear();
8
>
```

Can somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong here? I don't understand why it's adding together.. Thank you..

Source:

```
var Bike = function() {

  // Only change code below this line.
  var gear = 0;
  
  this.setGear = function(switchGear){
    gear += switchGear;
  };
  
  this.getGear = function() {
    return gear;
  };
};

var myBike = new Bike();
```

Comment: The `+=` operator means, "add the value of the right-hand operand to the current value of the variable on the left, and store the result in that variable."  It's adding because your program is telling it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose this is true of all bugs in software, but it's doing that *because you told it to!*

> gear += switchGear;

You said, add this value to the gear, so it did.

**Edit:** the OP's comment made his confusion more clear.

He seemed to think that the value of `gear` should "reset" in some fashion, and return to zero.

No, the steps in the function Bike are run once, when `new Bike()` is called.  The variable `gear` persists, and its value changes only when changed by a method.

Comment: So it just keeps adding the gears together even after the function has ended?

Comment: No, it adds gears every time you call myBike.setGear(); @13aal

Comment: @Ozrix Okay I get it, thank you, you're gonna have to wait for 6 minutes so I can accept this though

Answer (score 5):

```
gear += switchGear;
```

translates to

```
gear = gear + switchGear;
```

If you want to just set the value, do

```
gear = switchGear;
```